# R shiny - Simple Reactive issue

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build my first app in Shiny. 
I just want to select a name of variable so to plot one variable at a time but every time I am trying to pass the variable to the plot funnction i get or a xlim error or "attempt to apply non-function" my code below...Thank you very much!!

UI.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      "variable","The value to change below",
      list("Cylinders"="cyl",
           "Transmission"="am"))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("linePlot")
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  abc<-reactive({
   abc<-mtcars$input$variable
  })


  output$linePlot<-renderPlot({
    plot(abc(),type='l')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this:

`abc<-mtcars$input$variable`

Try doing this:

`abc <- mtcars[, input$variable]`

Your version won't work because it's starting with `mtcars`, looking for its list element named "input" (which doesn't exist), then looking for its list element named "variable" (which also doesn't exist).

The second version resolves what input$variable is (either "cyl" or "am") and then gets that column from `mtcars`.

Comment: or `mtcars[[input$variable]]`